# Run an external script from within lyx

Tags: lyx, scripts

Is it possible to run external scripts from within lyx, passing information about the current file as arguments?

I am thinking of usecases like

1. Interacting with file versioning software not natively supported.
2. Opening the file browser or a shell terminal in the directory of the lyx file.
3. Showing a list of paragraphs containing `FIXME` or `TODO`.

Comment: Sure, read the section in Help > Customization on Converters. Actually you seem like might like to read the whole customization manual. Also note that file versioning software is natively supported. See Help > Additional > Version Control in LyX.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Sadly I couldn't get it to work with it: I created a format `TEST_TODO`, a converter LyX -> TEST_TODO with a command `grep TODO $i > $o`. I tried `Alt-X buffer-export TEST_TODO` but it always says there was an error while exporting (and sadly lyx doesn't provide the error messages). Mpte that it does recognize the export format at least, the command `grep TODO $i > $o` shows up in the output log.